# C# Single insert method

Tags: c#, oop

I am working on a project for school to learn the way of using OOP in my code. Lately they told me that my group and myself could use a single method for inserting, updating, deleting and reading from the database. I tried it with reading and that went well. Today I thought is it possible to use a single method for inserting?

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid "how to make a single method for inserting and use it over and over?" is not sufficient information to help you. Which API/.NET functionality are you using? What is "the database"? What code do you have so far?

Comment: There are many tutorials and examples you can find online which show you how to use a database in C#.

Comment: I would suggest NOT to use single method for CRUD operations. Rather follow Single Responsibility Principle and apply different methods for each of your functions. Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)#Basic_concepts_and_related_topics

Comment: Well in the first period of this school year we started with c#, but not the OOP way and now far into the second period we found out that we were doing it wrong. So I know to use a database(had enough lessons about that last year). I am using .NET 4.5.2 . I am using a MySql database and I don't have much code because I had to change my project from non OOP to OOP.

Comment: it is possible to use a single select method and use it everywhere. For the select query I only need to send the table name to the select method and that worked for me.

Comment: How did you do it for reading? Post some code.

Comment: this is what I used for reading:

Comment: public DataTable dgv(String name)
        {
            openConn();
            comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + name + "";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter a = new MySqlDataAdapter(comm);
            a.Fill(table);
            closeConnection();
            return table;
        }

Comment: and I think it works the same way arround for deleting as well just send the id and the table name and you only have 1 delete method

Comment: I found the answer myself. I made 1 method with a switch case. I only need to ask for all parameters and for the tablename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use an `enum` to list all the actions possible.

```
public enum DbOperation
{
    Select,
    Insert,
    Delete,
    Update
}
```

and then use this as an argument to the method

```
public string DbCommand(DbOperation command, string arguments)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    switch(command)
    {
        case(DbOperation.Select):
            ...
            break;
        case(DbOperation.Insert:
            ...
            break;
        default:
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I will try this out and hope it helps. thank you @ja72